# C# Windows App A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: c#, windows-7

I'm seeing the following exception coming from a windows forms application on a windows 7 machine.  This just started happening on this machine.  It still works fine on others but not on a particular machine.

**Exception:**

```
  Exception Type: System.ApplicationException
  Message: A device attached to the system is not functioning.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
  Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
  TargetSite: Void AddTimerNative(System.Object, UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
  Source: mscorlib
```

**StackTrace Information:**

```
  at System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimerNative(Object state, UInt32 dueTime, UInt32 period, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimer(TimerCallback callback, Object state, UInt32 dueTime, UInt32 period StackCrawlMark & stackMark)
  at System.Threading.Timer.TimerSetup(TimerCallback callback, Object state, UInt32 dueTime, UInt32 period, StackCrawlMark & stackMark)
  at System.Threading.Timer..ctor(TimerCallback callBack, Object state, Int32 dueTime, Int32 period)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateCleanupTimer()
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.Startup()
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup.GetConnectionPool(DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPool(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionPoolGroup connectionPoolGroup)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState)
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

Also this seems to happen on the first query being ran in the application.  I can connect to the database server via ODBC connections on that machine so I know the machine can see the database server.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try running as Admin?

Comment: Somehow that eluded me but I would assume that they weren't running it as admin before.  I will try it and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: This should not require administrative privileges.  It sounds like that machine is messed up.

Comment: @SLaks,  I think you are right here.  I tried it anyway and still got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this error was related to a dll the program was using that our company wrote.  This only seems to occur in windows 7.

The problem was we were using a dll called **CryptBase.dll** but Windows 7 also comes with it's own  **CryptBase.dll**.  My companies version must have been conflicting with the windows version because as soon as we removed our version of this dll the program started working.