# .net application has a device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: c#, sql, .net-4.0

This is an occasional random error from my 32bit .net application when it connects to sql server.

```
System.ApplicationException: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
   at System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimerNative(Object state, UInt32 dueTime, UInt32 period, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimer(TimerCallback callback, Object state, UInt32 dueTime, UInt32 period, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Timer..ctor(TimerCallback callback, Object state, Int32 dueTime, Int32 period)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateCleanupTimer()
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.Startup()
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup.GetConnectionPool(DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPool(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionPoolGroup connectionPoolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

The `System.Threading.TimerBase.AddTimerNative()` method is an internal call, see [Microsoft source code.](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Threading/Timer@cs/1/Timer@cs)

I found another link on the web that discussed about CLR 
[Does CLR internally spawns a thread to respond to timer events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343733/does-clr-internally-spawns-a-thread-to-respond-to-timer-events)

Since I don't know  how `AddTimerNative` is implemented, I don't know the cause of work around this error.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187739/c-sharp-windows-app-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning

Comment: This is not the same problem. The program runs on Windows server 2008 R2. The program's component is a .net assembly instead of legacy win32 app/dll.

Comment: The solution could be the same. Have you tried it?

Comment: my program or any component does not use CryptBase.dll

Comment: Maybe there's another assembly that is causing a conflict. Try removing as many dependencies as possible and seeing if the problem goes away.